# How to add header to the http response of Geoserver

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, http-headers

Add a specific header to the http response of Geoserver, to allow cross domains request and avoid XMLHttpRequest On Load error.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the accepted way to solve this problem. As answered in another question of [yours](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/while-developing-stage-is-proxy-cgi-required-to-get-openlayers-wmsgetfeatureinf) the correct method is to create a proxy script or similar functionality in your web application.

For some of the Geoserver responses it may be possible to configure it around this by ensuring the responses are in GeoJSON format ect but you would severely limit the functionality provided by Geoserver.